# Intuit QBO accessToken created from refreshToken does not work only for one account

Tags: oauth-2.0, intuit-partner-platform

I am having issue only with one QuickBooks online account connecting to my app. When account initially connects to QBO everything works fine. But when time comes to refreshToken only one account has issues. Refresh token process works fine and I get new accessToken and new RefreshToken, but when I send data request it returns:

*General Authentication ErrorAuthenticationErrorGeneral:SRV-110-Authentication Failure , statusCode: 401.*

And it happens only to one account. This particular account needs to disconnect from QBO and reconnect all the time. Any idea? did anyone encounter the same issue?